# How do I pass in a string parameter that can either be one or two within a method? selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I wish to use this method in another method, but the problem is chooseFleet can either be one or two. How to do this in C#?

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("UserMgt")]
public void CompleteRegProcessPass(string role, string chooseFleet)
{
    var blobClient = new AzureStorageBlobClient(AzureStorageBlobClient);
    _regRep.btnAddUser.Click();

    objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.firstNameAdd, userName);
    objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.lastNameAdd, "Smithy");
    objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.userEmailAdd, emailID);
    objCommon.EnterText(_regRep.userTelephoneAdd, "12345678901");
    objCommon.Exists(_regRep.userRoleManager, 10);
    objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(**role**);
    objCommon.Exists(_regRep.chooseFleet, 5);
    objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(cf1);
            objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(cf2);
    objCommon.Click(_regRep.btnSaveUser);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public void CompleteRegProcessPass(string role, params string[] chooseFleet)
```

You can call it like:

```
CompleteRegProcessPass("role", "cf1");
CompleteRegProcessPass("role", "cf1", "cf2");
```

At the same time it's possible to call it like this:

```
CompleteRegProcessPass("role");
CompleteRegProcessPass("role", "cf1", "cf2", "cf3");
```

To get the best from both worlds:

```
public void CompleteRegProcessPass(string role, string chooseFleet1) =>
    CompleteRegProcessPassImpl(role, chooseFleet1);

public void CompleteRegProcessPass(string role, string chooseFleet1, string chooseFleet2) =>
    CompleteRegProcessPassImpl(role, chooseFleet1, chooseFleet2);

private void CompleteRegProcessPassImpl(string role, params string[] chooseFleet)
{
    ...
    foreach(var cf in chooseFleet)
    {
        objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick(cf);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'role' of 'TC02_UserManagement.CompleteRegProcessPass(string, params string[])' but the method itself won't run then?

Comment: I don't understand CompleteRegProcessPassImpl method, can you explain please?

Comment: @Butler In this method you should implement general logic to handle `string[] chooseFleet`.

Comment: @Butler what do you do with the 2nd chooseFleet? Add an example of your method for case `public void CompleteRegProcessPass(string role, string cf1, string cf2)`

Comment: Basically, the role and cf1 choose from a menu so in my code role = _regRep.userRoleManager and cf1or/andcf2 is this _regRep.chooseFleet and again if you can imagine a list table it will choose cf1 and cf2 highlight it and press save

Comment: So essentially I am highlighting one specific role and 2 cf's and pressing save if that makes sense.  But I cannot use existing test method because it does not allow paramters....selenium c# and VS

Comment: @Butler you want to call `objCommon.ScrollInToViewAndClick` for each cf, right?

Comment: Yes but some calls might be one cf and another call might be 2 cf's

Comment: @Butler If you have 1 cf - call `CompleteRegProcessPass(string role, string chooseFleet1)`, if you have 2 cf - call `CompleteRegProcessPass(string role, string chooseFleet1, string chooseFleet2)`

Comment: In your loop how do you list cf1, with cf2?

Comment: @Butler because I can use `foreach` with array `string[] chooseFleet`

Answer (score 0):

you can take advantage of Enum, or create a static class with constant values.

Enum Approach :

```
public enum FleetType {One=1, Two=2}

public void CompleteRegProcessPassV2(string role, FleetType chooseFleet)
{
    var fleet = (int) chooseFleet;
    CompleteRegProcessPass(role, chooseFleet.ToString());
}
```

static class :

```
public static class FleetType 
{
    public const string One = "1";

    public const string Two = "2";
}

public void CompleteRegProcessPassV2(string role, FleetType chooseFleet)
{
    CompleteRegProcessPass(role, chooseFleet);
}
```

this will restrict the input to 1 or 2 (as string). If you want to pass more string values, then you can pass string array, as mtkachenko answer.

Comment: Sorry guys I am new to selenium c#, how does my existing test method still run?

Comment: No overload for methods CompleteProcessPass takes two arguments, error!

Comment: How about two different multiple parameters i.e. multiple roles, and multiple fleets?